# need help on sed and awk command?

Tags: unix, sed, awk

INPUT FILE :

O,ff,$1123.81,ty,20100608,jjj,,13.180002,,,,

O,gg,$1794.06,jui,20100608,jjj,,13.180008,,,,

O,gg,$1794.06,jui,20100608,jjj,,13.180008,,,,

where ever ,, occurs in the input file i need to replace with , ,(space between,,) could anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g' inputfile
```

As bash-o-logist points out, the desired result for things like `,,,,` might be `, , , ,`.  If so then this could be used (run the command twice):

```
sed -e 's/,,/, ,/g; s/,,/, ,/g' inputfile
```

Comment: i hope this will effect only one time.. i need to do for entire file

Comment: This will work for every line.  If you omit the `g`, it will affect the first double-comma on every line, instead of every pair on every line.

Comment: @jcrshankar: I may not understand your question, but the sed script will replace all instances in the file.

Comment: I am not sure how OP wants his output, but this will only change `,,`.  because there may be `,,,,`, output will look like this `, ,, ,`. There is still `,,` left.

Comment: @bash-o-logist:  That's a good point; you may be correct about that.  I'm unsure.

Comment: yup bash its giving , ,, , .but i need like , , , ,

Answer (score 3):

A pure bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# tested on bash 4

while read -r line
do
    while [[ $line =~ ,, ]]
    do
        line=${line//,,/, ,}
    done
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

Sample output

```
bash4> bash comma.sh
O,ff,$1123.81,ty,20100608,jjj, ,13.180002, , , ,
O,gg,$1794.06,jui,20100608,jjj, ,13.180008, , , ,
O,gg,$1794.06,jui,20100608,jjj, ,13.180008, , , ,
```

Note, that the extra while loop is used to change subsequent `,,` to `, ,`

Comment: yup, thanks bash. i hope this will help. i check this and ask furthor help

Comment: nice one. pure bash without sed... yeah ; )

Comment: what is while [[ $line =~ ,, ]] will do, please tell me the equvalent statement in ksh?

Comment: that is just to check whether there is any more `,,`. You can use `case` or `if` statement to check as well.